# Eclipse Luna and Class with Large number of methods

Tags: eclipse, jogl

I needed to 'wrap' (for academic purposes) the GL2 interface in a class of mine that uses delegation to the current GLContext, something like:

```java
public abstract class GL2Wrapper implements GL2 {

    private GL2 current() {
        return GLContext.getCurrentGL().getGL2();
    }

    // delegated methods here

    public void glEnableClientState(int arrayName) {
        current().glEnableClientState(arrayName);
    }

    // ... (2000+ methods to go)

}

// Somewhere else
public class GlWindow extends GLWrapper {
    public GlWindow() {
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
            glVertex3f( 1, 0, 0);
            glVertex3f( 0, 1, 0);
            glVertex3f(-1, 0, 0);
        glEnd();
    }
}
```

It all works fine in runtime, but the class ends up with 2000+ methods.

I don't have a doubt that the code design is 'arguable', my question is more Eclipse Luna related.

Eclipse Luna hangs every time I use any type of auto-completion in the `GlWindow` class. It gets worst if I need to add something in `GL2Wrapper`.

I didn't have this problem (at least not this bad) in Eclipse Kepler and before.

Is there any eclipse configuration (maybe compiler related) that can help me leverage the problem?

Thanks in advance,
Regards,
LL

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an Eclipse [bug 433515 - Eclipse freezes every few minutes](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=433515).

> Same kind of issue for me when calling autocompletion in Javascript code into a JSP page or Javascript file, or even just hovering with the mouse a JavaScript code. The memory usage is playing the yoyo and Eclipse freezes.